# How to add toggle effect to a sprite image within an onlick function?

Tags: onclick, toggle, sprite

I have a **VIEW ITEMS**  button. And some content below that which is hidden initially.

**VIEW ITEM** is the TEXT with a sprite Image of PLUS and MINUS symbol.

What I need is that, when I click on the **VIEW ITEMS** button I need to slide down the below content as like accordion effect and the **PLUS** image should be changed to **MINUS** and vice versa.

Accordion part is working perfectly

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/abuisaacm/jLpre/2/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slide_down_container').hide();
    $('.viewBtnCtnr').on('click', function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
        $(this).children('div.btnImg').addClass("changePosition");
    });
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to change the image. by using **toggleClass()**

Here is my updated script code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.slide_down_container').hide();
$('.viewBtnCtnr').on('click', function() {
   $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
       $(this).children('div.btnImg').toggleClass("changePosition");
    });
});
```

I have also updated the fiddle too. here is the fiddle that works perfectly what I want to be.

[JSFIDDLE UPDATED](http://jsfiddle.net/abuisaacm/jLpre/3/)